# Law of large numbers for continuous periodic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R},$ with period 1. Prove that
$$
\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f\left(n \theta\right)=\int_{0}^1 f(t) \ dt
$$
for every irrational number $\theta$.

My attempt: I tried expanding $f$ in it's fourier series. But I am unable to proceed further. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the traditional approach is to show that the equality is true for Fourier basis elements and then extending that to $f$ via uniform approximation.

Comment: You just need to show that $\frac{\#\{n\le N: (n\theta\mod 1)\in(a,b)\}}{N}\to b-a$ for all $0<a<b<1$ - i.e. that discrete measure on the left converges to standard uniform.

Comment: @Yeldarbskich: How do you show the same for Fourier basis elements ?